# add user and assign role in aspnet membership through sql servers SP

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, asp.net-membership

Tech - asp.net 3.5, Sql server 2005

I have integrate aspnet membership for my webapplication.

I am adding some users (member) from importing excel file.

So how can I add that user and role of that user in aspnet membership tables?

NOTE - I have SP which is used to add member in DB from uploaded excel file, I have wrote insert trriger on membertable.

Comment: Use aspnet_Users_CreateUser to create the user and aspnet_UsersInRoles_AddUsersToRoles to add them to a role. Although I would recommend you follow the advise given below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not insert DB records manually. Use .NET's Membership Provider's stored procedures to do that, for example `aspnet_Membership_CreateUser` and `aspnet_Roles_CreateRole`.

But better off, use .NET's classes/methods to do that. They encapsulate the whole mechanism for you:

- [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx)
- [Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478950.aspx)

First you create a user, then you (optionally) attach role(s) to.

**UPDATE December 2015**

Folks keep reading this. It's important to know that for a few years now, there is a totally different paradigm, [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity). please use it instead of the old Membership Provider.

Answer (score 5):

Abhi you should use

```
     //to create a user
     MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(UserName, Password, Email);
     //to attach created user some role
     Roles.AddUserToRole(newUser.UserName, role);
```

**Update**

For that you can for for membership stored procedure **aspnet_Membership_CreateUser** to create a user or you can create one for you to insert data into user and userinroles table.
I would encourage you to refer [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx)

Comment: This is fine.. I am looking for create membership from Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do INSERT in the AspNetUsers table with empty PasswordHash and SecurityStamp. Then we have a "forgot password" flow that establishes credentials using ASP.NET Membership.